# Manually-defined axis labels for Matplotlib imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Gives the following figure:

[image]

However, instead of the axis labels corresponding to the index in the array, I want to manually define them. For example, instead of the axis labels being (0, 2, 4, 6, 8) as above, I want them to be (0, 10, 20, 30 ...).

Here is the code I have tried for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))
labels = range(0, 100, 10)
plt.imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.yticks(labels)
plt.show()
```

However, this gives the following figure:

[image]

How can I achieve a figure with an appearance like the first one, but with axis labels like the second one?

Answer (score 9):

The best way to do this is to modify the extent values in argument of your imshow :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest', extent=[0, 100, 0, 100])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Define your axes and modify the xticklabels, not the axis itself.  Something like this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 10))
ax1.imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_xticklabels(['', 0,10,20,30,40])
```